# Javascript file does not execute

Tags: javascript, html

I have written a very simple countdown timer in JavaScript that I have hardcoded to tell a user the number of days left until a certain date. This is then supposed to be shown on a web page.

Here is the JavaScript:

```
var message, days;
if (new Date().getMonth() === 6) {
    days = 34 - new Date().getDate();
    message = "Coming in " + days + " days";
} else if (new Date().getMonth() === 7) {
    if (new Date().getDate() > 2) {
        message = "Almost there!";
    } else if (new Date().getDate() === 2) {
        message = "Coming in 1 day";
    } else {
        days = 3 - new Date().getDate();
        message = "Coming in " + days + " days";
    }
} else {
    message = "Coming soon";
}
document.getElementById("coming_soon").innerHTML = message;
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<span id="coming_soon"></span>
```

The problem is that if I **inline** the JavaScript, it runs perfectly and the countdown is shown. If, however, I include it as a **separate** `.js` file, the countdown is not shown.

How can I include this as a separate file and still have it run and show the countdown?

I am a complete beginner to JavaScript, and somewhere between intermediate and beginner in HTML.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Include it in a `document.ready` and reference that file in your page bottom should work.

Comment: @Justcode I'm sorry, I don't understand your suggestion. I am a COMPLETE beginner with JavaScript. Literally started yesterday.

Comment: ok then i am posting this as a answer this is big to explain

Comment: @Justcode Surely my problem is just that I am using some syntax that only works when it is included inline in the HTML?

Comment: how are you including the external js file into your HTML page? Do you have the right path so the file is actually being included?

Comment: I'm including it with this line:`<script src="/js/coming_soon.js"></script>` and it's in the `/js` directory.

Comment: What does the JavaScript error console in your browser say.

Comment: Are you moving the script element when you switch to using an external file?

Comment: @Quentin I'm a complete beginner, but I think I found the right console in Firefox and here is what is says: `Use of getUserData() or setUserData() is deprecated.  Use WeakMap or element.dataset instead.` I'm not sure what you mean by moving the script element, but the HTML code remains identical.

Comment: OK, so if you're using an absolute path like that, how are you viewing the HTML file?

Comment: @Quentin I get the same error if I put the JavaScript code inline in the HTML, but it works and I get my "Coming in..." message.

Comment: @sevenseacat I'm viewing it in Firefox. All the code is on a server, not on my own computer.

Comment: this is going around in circles with half-answers... is including the JS  rendering a 404? Is the path to the JS correct?

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm using incorrect terminology and for not understanding questions. I am a complete beginner in JavaScript, and I've only been coding HTML and CSS for a couple of months. I am not in any way proficient. @sevenseacat The JavaScript file is indeed in the correct directory and the path is 100% correct.

Comment: @nisse-engström has fixed my mistake! See below.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, everyone! I appreciate it sincerely!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are there any messages in the browser's error console? Make sure that the script is included **after** the `<span>` element that you are trying to modify, or use the [`defer` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-defer) on the `<script>` element. Otherwise, `getElementById()` will not find it.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

Without jQuery and also for older IE's

```
var eventPrefix = "";
if (typeof window.addEventListener === "undefined" && window.attachEvent) {
    eventPrefix = "on";
    window.addEventListener = window.attachEvent;
}

if (typeof window.addEventListener !== "undefined") {
    window.addEventListener(eventPrefix + 'load',  function() {
        var message, days;
        if (new Date().getMonth() === 6) {
            days = 34 - new Date().getDate();
            message = "Coming in " + days + " days";
        } else if (new Date().getMonth() === 7) {
            if (new Date().getDate() > 2) {
                message = "Almost there!";
            } else if (new Date().getDate() === 2) {
                message = "Coming in 1 day";
            } else {
                days = 3 - new Date().getDate();
                message = "Coming in " + days + " days";
            }
        } else {
            message = "Coming soon";
        }
        document.getElementById("coming_soon").innerHTML = message;
    });
}
```

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/4JPCP/1/show/

Optimized code: http://jsfiddle.net/4JPCP/3/

Comment: Adding the complexity of event listeners is unnecessary for such a simple problem. Especially considering that the OP is an absolute beginner.

Answer (score -1):

**Edit:**
IIFE are redundant in this case, since OP's code it's not self contained in a function.
However, I could leave the answer here if anyone wants to dive deeper into the argument.

---

You may also wants to explore what are commonly called **Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)**.

See Bel Alman website for more information:
http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Basically, by wrapping your code with this syntax, you're telling the browser to immediately execute your function, and this do the trick:

```
(function(){ 
  /* your code */ 
})();
```

See this working Plunker with your code: http://plnkr.co/edit/cPObPCqVhavvWLtQbldd?p=preview

Comment: This is almost the opposite of what the OP wants. The execution actually needed to be delayed.

Comment: It's not the opposite at all, since it's working. However, I now think that the IIFE may be redundant, since OP's code is not in a function.